# Consuming xml flat files in Salesforce

Tags: apex, webservices, xml, xmlparsing

I have a business requirement, which says that xml files (with table and row like elements) are attached (uploaded) to a custom object, which will be done through the REST API. That's done. Now I would need to open that attachment by code (could also be a file object) and read parts of that xml file into a custom object, and then send that xml to an external web service. I could not find an Salesforce documented way to do so. I do appreciate any hint/sample/idea on that.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Please share the code you tried to solve your problem. Please also check out [Help Center: How to ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/asking).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the volume of data is not huge, then the simplest way to read the data is to use [Apex's DOM parser](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_xml_dom_document.htm#apex_classes_xml_dom_document):

```
Dom.Document doc = new Dom.Document();
doc.load(xml);
```

and then the [various methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_xml_dom_xmlnode.htm#apex_classes_xml_dom_xmlnode) that let you walk around the parsed structure.

The same classes work well for when you want to create XML: they handle things like the escaping of characters in strings and allow nested structures to be built up fairly easily. (Building XML by appending strings is pretty fragile.)